# Google Drive API ImportError

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pyopenssl

I am trying to perform authentication at domain level of **Google Drive API(Oauth2)**. For that I refer the google drive document link as below:

https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

I have already install openssl but then also get error

> > ImportError: cannot import name SignedJwtAsseionCredentials when trying to import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials.

Full traceback are as follows:

ERROR    2013-04-16 05:03:52,006 wsgi.py:219] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler
    handler = **import**(path[0])
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 692, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1766, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 692, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1630, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 692, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1577, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "D:\API\GoogleDrive\myapp\main.py", line 21, in 
    from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
ImportError: cannot import name SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

Can anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: could you provide the full traceback